# How do you display the current date of a field in a SelectDateWidget?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

One of my forms is an edit form. I'm trying to let users edit some data, including their existing birthday. However, when they go into the edit page, all the input fields have text already indicating the current value of that field.

However, the selectdatewidget is completely blank, even when the date is already saved. Users always have to change the date back to their original birthday and save, which is a hassle.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here is my form code:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    today = int(date.today().year)
    BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = (
        [i for i in reversed(range(1900,today))]
    )
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget = extras.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES), required=False)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Numbers only please'}, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('avatar','user','gender','phone','accomplishments','description',)
        exclude = ('user','birthday')
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect us to solve your problem from the description given here?? Do show us the code you have tried !!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a more general problem. My bad, I posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `__init__` method for ProfileForm and there set initial values for all fields:

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(self.ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['birthday'].initial = whatever_you_want
```

or you can pass initial values in time you creating Form:

```
form = ProfileForm(initial={'birthday': 'your_date'})
```